# Menu items missing on smartphone (any browser), work fine on desktop (any browser)

Tags: smartphone

When opening the main menu (hamburger icon top right) of [my page](http://goo.gl/rQgml8) (password = "shooga1") on a smartphone, menu items are not there - menu is empty. Opening the same menu on desktop, after reducing browser window to make it narrow like on a smartphone, the exact same menu works normally.

This problem occurs regardless of which mobile browser or desktop browser is used. Pretty puzzling, any suggestion as to what is the problem or how to solve it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the mobile menu is empty.

In your website, there is an object's id called `mobile-menu`, and when users use the mobile phone to check the menu, this area will become visible. 
(Normally it's invisible. When you touch the icon on the top-right side, it will become visible.)

But I can not see any code in this area. That means you designed the menu for desktop only and you maybe need to design the menu for mobile, too.

It's up to the framework you use. Maybe there are some methods that can be used to let the menu for mobile be the same as the menu for desktop.